# RecyclerView for Android Chat - Something missing. Unable to reach to place where it selects who sent?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, chat

An Android newbie here. I am building a chat app. The sent and received messages are not shown in the UI. I am able to send to server, but not getting displayed. Please help.

I put breakpoints in the code where it should bind data to the Views and inflate the layout, but that code is not at all getting triggered.

Askquestion Activity

```
public class Askquestion extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private static final String TAG = "Chatapp";

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;


    private RecyclerView.Adapter ChatappChatAdapter;

    private ArrayList<ChatappMsg> messages;

    private ImageView img_send;

    private EditText et_message;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_askquestion);

        int messageID = 111;

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_chat);
        ChatappChatAdapter = new ChatappChatAdapter(messageID, this,messages);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(ChatappChatAdapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



        messages = new ArrayList<>();

        //fetchMessages();

        img_send = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_send);
        et_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);



        //ChatappChatAdapter = new ChatappChatAdapter(messageID, this,messages);

        img_send.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == img_send)
            sendMessage();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

    private void sendMessage(){
        final String messageBody = et_message.getText().toString().trim();
        if(messageBody.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            return;
        String messageBy = "Someone";
        String messageAt = "sometime";
        String messageType = "type";
        int messageID = Integer.parseInt("111");


        //LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);


        recyclerView.setAdapter(ChatappChatAdapter);

        ChatappChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        ScrollToBottom();

        et_message.setText("");

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASEURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        final ChatappMsg ChatappMsg = new ChatappMsg(messageBody,messageAt,messageBy,messageType,messageID);

        Call<ChatappMsg> call = apiService.TalktoChatapp(ChatappMsg);

        Log.d(TAG, ""+ChatappMsg);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ChatappMsg>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ChatappMsg> call, Response<ChatappMsg> response) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ChatappMsg> call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }

    //method to scroll the recyclerview to bottom
    private void ScrollToBottom() {
        ChatappChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (ChatappChatAdapter.getItemCount() > 1)
            recyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, null, ChatappChatAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
    }


}
```

ChatappChatAdapter.java

```
public class ChatappChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatappChatAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "Adapter";

    private String messageBy;

    private int messageID;
    private Context context;

    private int SELF = 111;

    private ArrayList<ChatappMsg> messages;

    public ChatappChatAdapter(int messageID, Context context, ArrayList<ChatappMsg> messages) {
        this.messageID = messageID;
    //    this.messageBy = messageBy;
        this.context = context;
        this.messages = messages;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView;
        // if else loop to identify if the message is sent message or received message
        //Creating view
//        View itemView;
        //if view type is self
        if (viewType == SELF) {

            Log.i(TAG,"ViewType Defined as Self" );
            //Inflating the layout self
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.row_sent_message_text, parent, false);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG,"ViewType Defined as Not Self" );

            //else inflating the layout others
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.row_received_message_text, parent, false);
        }

        Log.i(TAG,"Retuened" );
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ChatappChatAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ChatappMsg msg = messages.get(position);
        ((ViewHolder) holder).messageBody.setText(msg.getMessageBody());

        ((ViewHolder) holder).messageAt.setText(msg.getMessageAt());

        ((ViewHolder) holder).messageBy.setText(msg.getMessageBy());

    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        ChatappMsg msg = messages.get(position);

        if(msg.getMessageID() == messageID ) {
            return SELF;

        }
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView messageBody;
        public TextView messageAt;
        public TextView messageBy;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            messageBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageBody);
            messageAt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageAt);
            messageBy = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageBy);

        }
    }
}
```

Chatapp Model.

```
public class ChatappMsg {

    private String messageBody;
    private String messageAt;
    private String messageBy;
    private String messageType;
    private int messageID;

    public String getMessageBody() {
        return messageBody;
    }

    public void setMessageBody(String messageBody) {
        this.messageBody = messageBody;
    }

    public String getMessageAt() {
        return messageAt;
    }

    public void setMessageAt(String messageAt) {
        this.messageAt = messageAt;
    }

    public String getMessageBy() {
        return messageBy;
    }

    public void setMessageBy(String messageBy) {
        this.messageBy = messageBy;
    }

    public String getMessageType() {
        return messageType;
    }

    public void setMessageType(String messageType) {
        this.messageType = messageType;
    }

    public int getMessageID() {
        return messageID;
    }

    public void setMessageID(int messageID) {
        this.messageID = messageID;
    }

    public ChatappMsg(String messageBody, String messageAt, String messageBy, String messageType, int messageID) {
        this.messageBody = messageBody;
        this.messageAt = messageAt;
        this.messageBy = messageBy;
        this.messageType = messageType;
        this.messageID = messageID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ChatappMsg{" +
                "messageBody='" + messageBody + '\'' +
                ", messageAt='" + messageAt + '\'' +
                ", messageBy='" + messageBy + '\'' +
                ", messageType='" + messageType + '\'' +
                ", messageID='" + messageID + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Help me in understanding what am I missing here.

I believe it might be an issue with the viewType or the message ID. How to fix? What should be the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**You are returning 0 in getItemCount()** method in adapter.

Can you change it to

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }
```

in your **ChatappChatAdapter** and try again

Comment: This is what I am getting when I do a messages.size();   
 `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference`

Comment: if you create messages list after creating adapter this is normal! and where do you fill the messages list ? I can not see that in your code also ?